# How can I protect my data from certain apps in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, user-accounts, uac, user-profiles

UAC helps protect the *system* from getting trashed by non-privileged apps. But how can I protect my data from getting trashed or misused by apps?

Example 1: An app silently modifies the tags in all my music files.

Example 2: An app reads my email client's contact list and sends it off somewhere.

Example 3: An app modifies my personal settings for Windows in the registry (e.g. disables the auto insert notification feature for optical drives).

The three examples above have all happened to me at various times. They can happen because any app running as "me" can do what it wants with any data created by "me". Essentially, my data is exposed to **everything**.

Surely, after so many versions since NT, Windows has a native means by which to control what apps can and can't access – whether that be folders on disk or keys in the registry.

I can't find anything built into Windows 7 that accomplishes what I'm after. Any ideas? Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Don't install "dodgy apps". Backup your data.

Comment: @DavidPostill Hah, true, goes without saying I think. I shouldn't have used the word *dodgy* as that implies malicious (have modified the question). Even reputable apps sometimes do things I personally consider 'dodgy', as in the three examples I gave.

Comment: Yes, but those apps won't do anything until **you** execute them and thus ask them to do something to your files/data. If you don't fully understand what they are going to do then backup first **then** run the app.

Comment: @DavidPostill What you're suggesting is an *all or nothing* approach to the problem. My question is about how one can control what an app has access to. In some cases, controlling access to data would be a better solution than entirely giving up on an otherwise useful app.

Comment: Back up important data to a safe place that is out of reach from bad acting programs. .

Comment: @Moab Um why are you just repeating what DavidPostill already said above?

Comment: I can solve half your problem.  I've used a free program called WinPatrol (https://www.winpatrol.com/winpatrol/) since it came out.  Any attempt to change the OS (registry, startup programs, etc.), are blocked pending your approval (you can whitelist and blacklist to automate specific applications).   Phenomenal program.  I don't have a solution for protecting files.

Comment: @misha256 because too many times people ignore this advice then come back here trying to recover files.

Comment: Acronis had a "Try & decide" feature, but in the 2015 version they [decided to remove it](https://kb.acronis.com/content/48608) to some [users' dismay](https://forum.acronis.com/forum/65108). Maybe because they do not want to invest in [GTP support](https://kb.acronis.com/content/44348).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows 8.1 has a feature which lets you create a user account that is used by a specific app, but Windows 7 does not have a *convenient* way of doing this for individual apps.

You can create separate accounts with different filesystem and Registry permissions, then launch the app under the appropriate account by using the [runas](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/419-run-different-user.html) feature.

Another alternative would be to use a program like [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/) which lets you install and run software in its own virtual sandbox, preventing access to the rest of your system.

Comment: This might just work for apps I know do questionable things. I'd have to give permissions to the "new user" to allow it access to some of my data... I need to test this out...

Comment: @misha256 I added a link to Sandboxie, which you may also find useful.

Comment: I was specifically looking for an answer/solution that is *native* to Windows (i.e. doesn't require the use of 3rd party software). Turns out that creating a separate account and running apps under that account is THE way to do this. Interesting to observe that Android OS does exactly this with its apps (each app gets its own account). Takes a bit of time to set up the account and permissions but, once that's done, it works very well indeed. Thanks for the good answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** I do not work for Faronics and am not affiliated with them in any way.

It looks to me that you want something like [Faronics Deep Freeze](http://www.faronics.com/en-uk/products/deep-freeze/standard/) and [Data Igloo](http://www.faronics.com/en-uk/products/data-igloo/). It works by having a low-level driver prevent any permanent changes from being made to the disk when protection is active.

Applications can use and modify data however they like but once the system reboots, it's as good as new with all the changes wiped. I guess you could say it's somewhat similar to restoring a VM snapshot.

This image might help understand how it works (from Faronics' website):
[image: Faronics Deep Freeze - How it works]

Some other [alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/deep-freeze/) (that I haven't tried) include:

1. [Rollback Rx](http://www.horizondatasys.com/en/products_and_solutions.aspx?ProductId=1#Features) (free)
2. [Toolwiz Time Freeze](http://www.toolwiz.com/products/toolwiz-time-freeze/) (free)
3. [WinJail](http://www.winquota.com/wj/) (paid)
4. [chroot for Windows](http://www.airesoft.co.uk/chroot) (free)
5. [Reboot Restore Rx](http://www.horizondatasys.com/en/products_and_solutions.aspx?ProductId=18#Features) (free)

Comment: That's good for kiosks or other one time use computers, but for normal desktop usage this will be extremely inconvenient because even legitimate changes would be rolled back. Also it doesn't protect from apps simply reading (not writing) and uploading contacts/other personal data to a remote server.

Comment: @AndréDaniel It certainly won't protect against data theft, but that's why you run suspicious programs in a VM. I don't think anything can prevent against example 2 in the question unless the contact list itself is encrypted. Also, you don't have to always keep the system frozen, you can thaw (Deep Freeze terminology) it when you're not using suspicious programs. You can also select which partitions get frozen, so even when the system drive is protected, you could write your changes to other partitions that aren't. Registry & filesystem changes on the system drive will be reverted though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things:

Use file permissions as rob suggested.

Set a read-only flag on everything you want to prevent being modified. This is not a panacea, but it easier to do and will solve the issue of protecting files like music and photos.